# Best Hardware for Endian Firewall Community Edition

Tags: linux, firewall, hardware, ethernet

What would be the best hardware solution with 3+ Ethernet ports to install Endian Firewall Community Edition on? I am currently using a Jetaway mini-ITX enclosure with a Jetaway board and am not happy with it.

I cannot boot the machine w/o the network cables UNPLUGGED, otherwise the links for some reason will not be active. So I have to boot the box, then plug the cables in. On top of that for some reason it does not detect the PHY ethernet NIC.

So, any ideas on alternative small form factor hardware?

Comment: The term "best" is very subjective. Perhaps you should rephrase the question and be clearer about exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

[PCEngines](http://pcengines.ch/) has nice boards and this [one](http://pcengines.ch/alix2d13.htm) should suit you.